# Making factories in FactoryGirl more DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I have a recurring pattern when creating factories for database views using FactoryGirl. An example of how a factory can look like:

```
factory :site_brand do
  brand
  brand_translation
  country

  initialize_with do
    SiteBrand.where(brand_id: attributes[:brand].id, country_id: attributes[:country].id).first
  end
end
```

The only thing unique here is "brand". I have other cases for "category", "item" and so on. I'm trying to figure out if I can make this more DRY, without needing to monkey patch FactoryGirl.

Answer (score 1):

Have  you tried using [traits](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/23673635798/remove-duplication-with-factorygirls-traits)?

Comment: I have looked at traits, I'm not sure but I think I would need to pass an argument to a trait to make it work, which traits don't support. Or am I missing something else?